# Why is my recursive function not returning the last element in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

so i was going through the course of FreeCodecamp and stumbled upon this task which I solved with a for-loop. But to test my knowledge about recursive function I wanted to give it a try. But for some reason the array at the end only contains the third and second element.

Code:

Task from:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/es6/create-strings-using-template-literals

```
const result = {
    success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
    failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],
    skipped: ["no-extra-semi", "no-dup-keys"]
  };

  const failureItems = [];

  function makeList(arr) {
    // Only change code below this line
  
    // for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    // {
    //   failureItems.push(`<li class="text-warning">${arr[i]}</li>`);
    // }  
    
    if(arr.length === 1){
      return arr[0];
    } else {
      failureItems.push(`<li class="text-warning">${arr.pop()}</li>`);
      if(arr.length >= 1){
        makeList(arr);}
    }
    console.log("Log before return:" + failureItems[0]);  
    // Only change code above this line
    return failureItems;
  }
  const failuresList = makeList(result.failure);
  console.log(`Failure list is ${failuresList}`);
```

I added console.log where I thought the problem occurs but I just cant pinpoint the line that gives me trouble.

Comment: when do you think you are pushing the first element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not pushing first element ever.

although recursion might not be the best solution the way you are doing it.. but you can recurse till array is empty

```js
if(arr.length === 0){
      return;
    } else {
      failureItems.push(`<li class="text-warning">${arr.pop()}</li>`);
      if(arr.length >= 1){
        makeList(arr);}
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, the recursion was more of a personal challenge.
Big thanks for the fast and precise answer!

Comment: not criticising but apart from problem solving skills.. work on debugging skills as well , you have no idea how helpful it is in larger codebases

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mostly correct, and the only reason why it doesn't give each output is the base condition i.e. where the recursion should end at.

The only base condition that is appropriate for pushing elements here is till the array is empty. This allows you to actually push the first element as well.

The revised code is as follows:

```
const result = {
    success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
    failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],
    skipped: ["no-extra-semi", "no-dup-keys"]
  };

  const failureItems = [];

  function makeList(arr) {
    
    // your base condition

    if(arr.length === 0){
      return;
    } else {
      failureItems.push(`<li class="text-warning">${arr.pop()}</li>`);
    }
    if(arr.length >= 1){
        makeList(arr);}
    console.log("Log before return:" + failureItems[0]);  
    
    // Only change code above this line
    return failureItems;
  }
  const failuresList = makeList(result.failure);
  console.log(`Failure list is ${failuresList}`);
```

The recursive function is called one by one for each element in the array and it is pushed into the list till the array becomes empty i.e.

> arr.length === 0

Kindly upvote if it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You code, even once corrected by the other answers, has two real problems.

First, you're reversing the array as you go.  This is a result of repeatedly calling `pop`, moving from right to left through the input array, and then placing the result at the end of the output array with `push`, now moving left to right.

Second, and worse, you are mutating the input in an unrecoverable manner.  By calling `pop`, you are destroying your `result` object.  If you log it when you're done, you'll see that `result.failure` is now an empty array.  Uggh!

A simple way to get around these problems is to use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert an array of values into another one by applying the same function to each value:

```js
const makeList = (arr) => 
  arr .map (reason => `<li class="text-warning">${reason}</li>`)

const result = {
  success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
  failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],
  skipped: ["no-extra-semi", "no-dup-keys"]
}

const failuresList = makeList (result .failure)
console .log (`Failure list is ${failuresList}`)
```

If you really want to do this recursively, you might try something like

```js
const makeList = (reasons) =>
  reasons .length == 0 
    ? []
    : [`<li class="text-warning">${reasons [0]}</li>`, ...makeList (reasons .slice (1))]
```

Or the slightly more succinct variant I would prefer:

```js
const makeList = ([reason, ...reasons]) => 
  reason == undefined 
    ? [] 
    : [`<li class="text-warning">${reason}</li>`, ...makeList (reasons)]
```